# Mongoose aggregate match field value equals to variable without $expr?

Tags: mongoose, aggregation-framework

I want to use aggregate to populate documents relations. I have the following query:

```
db.A.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "B",
      let: {
        a_id: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            a_id: "$$a_id"
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "b"
    }
  }
])
```

Example database looks like this:

```
db={
  A: [
    {
      _id: 0,
      
    },
    {
      _id: 1,
      
    }
  ],
  B: [
    {
      _id: 2,
      a_id: 0,
      
    },
    {
      _id: 3,
      a_id: 1
    }
  ]
}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BkLYZGb7CPU)

I can't use `$expr` as it's not supported by the platform I use. Is there a way to match the field value with variable without using it?

Comment: internal fields condition is only possible by `$expr`, you can use simple $lookup with localField and freignField. *I can't use $expr as it's not supported by the platform* which platform are you using?